# parse xml with jquery - bad xml format

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, parsing

i have this xml file:

```
<dist>
    <key>keynumber1</key>
    <string>value1</string>
    <key>keynumber2</key>
    <string>value2</string>
    <key>keynumber3</key>
    <string>value3</string>
    <key>keynumber4</key>
    <integer>value4</integer>
</dist>
```

how can i parse this with jquery like:

```
{ "dist": {"keynumber1":"value1", "keynumber2":"value2"}}
```

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is parsing xml with jQuery using $.parseXML(str);

Then I used this pretty function, created by [David Welsh](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json)

```
    function xmlToJson(xml) {

// Create the return object
var obj = {};

if (xml.nodeType == 1) { // element
    // do attributes
    if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
    obj["@attributes"] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
            var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
            obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
        }
    }
} else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { // text
    obj = xml.nodeValue;
}

// do children
if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
    for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
        var nodeName = item.nodeName;
        if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
            obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
        } else {
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName].length) == "undefined") {
                var old = obj[nodeName];
                obj[nodeName] = [];
                obj[nodeName].push(old);
            }
            obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
        }
    }
}
return obj;
};
```