# Searching and Sorting in an XML file containing location Coordinates

Tags: xml, cordova, xml-parsing

well i have a xml file that i use to store location names with their addresses and their co ordinates. i need this data to help locating tht location on map. now the xml file is huge as it contains large amount of data so i want to reduce the searching time as i want to deploy the app on the mobile platforms- android and iphone. What i exactly do is, get users current location and then parse the xml one by one, get the co ordinates , compute distance between location and user, and then if distance less than radius, print on the screen. **so any sorting or search algo can i implement here that will be on the users current location co ordinates???**

Comment: i think you should move the sorting part on native side as it would run much faster and then display location with distance can be done on javascript part with pure javascript function of using Google Map API

Comment: How "huge" is the file? Can you load the data into a datastructure in memory or is the file too big for that?

Comment: it'll contain list of locations of a country with various parameters and also their latitudes and longitudes...
@dhaval buddy i already have a function locally to compute distance frm the coordinates, i want to create a filter for selecting appropriate records dependin on the co ordinates of the records and the users current location

Comment: i would run down into different steps. convert xml to json so that you can iterate and extract required data (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552021/parse-xml-with-jquery-bad-xml-format). create an array of the distances and a map to store other data against distances for later retrieval, this is the part i am trying to propose you in native as it would be lengthy but you can still use the javascript and see how long it takes. once distance array is created you can use simple jquery sort function to order them based on distance.

Comment: once ordered you can use the distance to data map created earlier to do the rendering.

Comment: have you tried any solution??

Comment: i was thinkin of creatin a new database locally, using sql-lite may be, and thn query database as according to the need, i may use parameters like city, area,etc to sort the results.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constraint on using that XML file, OK. But do you also have a constraint on not using a database at all? Against keeping XML and a database both?

If not, you can store coordinates and a key to immediately seek in the XML file into a database. This will give you fast searches, and slower (but minimal) reads from the XML file.

If you also can not use a database, you may try and store coordinates and (again) keys to the XML file in another file, which will be far smaller, and inside which maybe you can organize some sort of tree-ordering or partitioning.

Finally if you can use ONLY the one XML file, you will have to quickly parse the file and extract the relevant coordinate information. This you can probably do with a regexp, by routinely reading enough data that you always have a full record in your memory search buffer (you need an estimate of the maximum record size to do this). But it looks expensive as all hell. I'd strongly push for some other way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

XML seems to be bad choice for the data. If you are in control of the way the data is stored, consider saving it into a database (as far as I know, Phonegap supports that) and searching in rectangular radius first. If you really have to use the XML, sorting it probably won't help much (coordinates are from 2-D set). Maybe you could break it into two files (one for each coordinate) and sort them, but it is really very ugly solution. The sorting can be achieved via XSLT, see for example [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/transform.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to recreate what hundreds/thousands of Database engineers have already tackled.   Hundreds of thousands of geeks have learned the sort methods and what is optimal and not. Then the smartest of these were hired by large corporations to put these algorithms in databases.

Your solution does not sound very robust.  XML is not intended for what you are doing.  Having said that, if you insist on using XML...

I would have at least 2 xml files - one that contained the data sorted by an artificial key and one that had the parameter(s) which you are going to search on.  Then you are going to have to do a seek on the latter file and then look it up on the former file.  Which coincidentally is roughly what databases do.

I would sincerely push for a web service that does the look-up/calculation for you. You can use an already existing one or create your own. It sounds like you need connectivity for your app to work anyway.

Comment: ys i need connectivity for the purpose. and what steps should i follow according to you in my case. use of xml is a thing tht cannot be changed, so hw exactly can i optimise it?? thanks for the answer.

Comment: provide some of your sample data in the question

Answer (score 0):

Very bad choice to do it top of XML. Bundle **[SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/)** to your application. It is SQLite extended of spatial features so then can do various queries on geo position data... including search for nearest geo point, or all in some radius. By SQL queries.
Parse XML data and put them to **SpatiaLite** DB file... it will be for sure smaller than original XML.